# Realtime data update to streamlit from python variable

Tags: python, streamlit

New to python world. I am trying to understand how to update realtime data in streamlit app.(Reference [Blog](https://blog.streamlit.io/how-to-build-a-real-time-live-dashboard-with-streamlit/)).

I am looping through the numbers 1 to 100, display the `number`  along with `number * 10`. But streamlit always shows number as 1. How can I update the numbers(realtime update) in streamlit?

My code:

```
import threading
import streamlit as st
import time

global val, multiply


def test_run():
    global val, multiply
    for x in range(1, 100):
        val = x
        multiply = val * 10
        print(val)
        time.sleep(1)
    return val, multiply


threading.Thread(target=test_run).start()

# dashboard title
st.title("Stramlit Learning")

# creating a single-element container.
placeholder = st.empty()

with placeholder.container():
    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
    col1.metric(label="Current Value", value=val)
    col2.metric(label="Multiply by 10 ", value=multiply)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code: Values of the variables will get updated in every second.

```py
import threading
import streamlit as st
import time
import queue


q = queue.Queue()

def test_run():
    for x in range(1, 100):
        val = x
        multiply = val * 10
        q.put((val, multiply))
        print(val)
        time.sleep(1)


def update_dashboard():
    while True:
        val, multiply = q.get()

        col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
        col1.metric(label="Current Value", value=val)
        col2.metric(label="Multiply by 10 ", value=multiply)


threading.Thread(target=test_run).start()

# dashboard title
st.title("Streamlit Learning")

with st.empty():
    update_dashboard()
```